# How to reinstate the default Xubuntu 14.04 applications menu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, appmenu, xfce-panel

I have accidently deleted the default Xubuntu 14.04 Applications menu, which used to look like this:

[image: Default Xubuntu 14.04 Applications menu screenshot]

However, I did manage to re-add an application menu (using `Panel` -> `Add new items` -> `Applications menu`. However, it just doesn't look the same as it used to.  For me, I now see:

[image: Xubuntu 14.04 Applications menu screenshot]

I have tried right clicking on the applications menu, and selecting `Properties`. However, none of the options in that menu seem to help.

Is there a way to get the default appearance back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `Whisker Menu` panel item.

[image]